# How to create a mock database from csv files for JOOQ?

Tags: java, csv, mocking, jooq

I have read the the following articles and tried to load data from csv for creating a mock database.

https://blog.jooq.org/tag/mock-data/

https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/importing/importing-csv/

But ending up with the following exceptions.

**error details :**

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [insert into `database_name`.`table_name` (`id`, `epoch_time`) values (?, ?)]; Invalid SQL: insert into `database_name`.`table_name` (`id`, `epoch_time`) values (?, ?)
```

The number of processed rows : 1

The number of stored rows (INSERT or UPDATE) : 0

The number of ignored rows (due to errors, or duplicate rule) : 1

Query query = error.query();

System.out.println(query.getSQL());

```
insert into `database_name`.`table_name` (`id`, `epoch_time`) values (?, ?)
```

System.out.println(query.getBindValues());

`[50331, 1556686800]`

System.out.println(query.getParams());

`{1=50331, 2=1556686800}`

**Question**

My understanding of Jooq is not great.

1. Are the values not being binded in the SQL above  ?
2. I am not sure how to add loading CSV files functionality in the code below. Csv Loader gives back `Loader<Record>`, where as `MockResult` requires `Result<Record>`.

   ```
   @Override
   public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext context) 
   throws SQLException {

   // Use ordinary jOOQ API to create an org.jooq.Result object.
   // You can also use ordinary jOOQ API to load CSV files or
   // other formats, here!
   DSLContext create = DSL.using(configuration);
   Result<MyTableRecord> result = create.newResult(MY_TABLE);
   result.add(create.newRecord(MY_TABLE));

   // Now, return 1-many results, depending on whether this is
   // a batch/multi-result context
   return new MockResult[] {
       new MockResult(1, result)
       };
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I have had this all wrong.

I was under the under the impression, you could load data into in-memory tables using the below API, and create a mock database consisting of a few required tables and run some  queries against it.

```
// Load data into the BOOK table from an input stream
// holding the CSV data.
create.loadInto(BOOK)
      .loadCSV(inputstream, encoding)
      .fields(BOOK.ID, BOOK.AUTHOR_ID, BOOK.TITLE)
      .execute();
```

Realized after spending a couple of hours figuring out how to load data from csv (described below), that **jooq**(an awesome api for writing queries) is not a database engine and can't actually execute queries against in-memory data.

**loading mock data from csv:**

```
@Override
public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext ctx) throws SQLException {


    List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("table_data.csv"));
    String csvString = strings.stream()
            .reduce(new StringJoiner("\n"), StringJoiner::add, StringJoiner::merge)
            .toString();

    DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.MYSQL);

    Result<Record> records = create.fetchFromCSV(csvString);
    List<YourTableDataRecord> tableDataList = records.into(YourTableDataRecord.class);

    Result<YourTableDataRecord> result = create.newResult(POJO_RERESENTING_THE_DATA);

    result.addAll(tableDataList);

    return new MockResult[]{
            new MockResult(result.size(), result)
    };
}
```

Note, the above solution can be done more efficiently, reading line by line and caching the results.

Also, a mock result should be created against each query. Read more here https://blog.jooq.org/tag/unit-testing/ under the section *Use jOOQ’s MockDataProvider for this*

Comment: Very interesting approach! You could of course also just use H2 as your in-memory database, and then query it using jOOQ directly, without mocking...